# Google Cloud Endpoints - Method does not exist - OpenAPI yaml specification

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, swagger, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I'm trying to setup a NodeJS REST API using Google Cloud Endpoints and Google App Engine. I've cloned the offical sample project from [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started) and set up Google Cloud Endpoints using the [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-app-engine). Out of the box, it works fine,but I tried adding another API endpoint for a GET request at `/`, but the response I get after I deploy and make the request is as follows:

```
{
 "code": 5,
 "message": "Method does not exist.",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "service_control"
  }
 ]
}
```

The APIs which came pre-configured works fine, but only new ones which I add aren't working.

I've configured the new endpoint properly in my NodeJS app (it works fine locally). The corresponding code I've **added** is:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Hello, world!' });
});
```

I've **added** the following to my `openapi.yaml` file:

```
paths:
  "/":
    get:
      description: "Returns the message \"Hello, World\""
      operationId: "root"
      produces:
      - "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Hello"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/helloMessage"
definitions:
  helloMessage:
    properties:
      message:
        type: "string"
```

After running `gcloud service-management deploy openapi.yaml` from a terminal to deploy and configure Google Cloud Endpoints, I got the service name and the service configuration ID, which I've replaced in `app.yaml`, in the format specified by the QuickStart

```
endpoints_api_service:
  name: echo-api.endpoints.[YOUR-PROJECT-ID].cloud.goog
  config_id: YOUR-CONFIG-ID
```

(That's the format, I've replaced `YOUR-PROJECT-ID` and `YOUR-CONFIG-ID` with the right ones)

I deployed the app to Google App Engine using `gcloud app deploy`. I can see the app running properly, via the Google App Engine console.

Yet, the GET method on `/` is not being identified as a valid endpoint and I get the response as stated above.

Am I missing something? I searched a lot about this problem, but didn't come across anything useful/similar!

P.S: By **added**, I mean, it is the code which I've added to the corresponding [GitHub cloned files](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started)

---

**EDIT:**
I changed the API endpoint from `/` to `/hello` and it works fine!! Unable to understand why the same functionality on `/` is not working on Google Cloud Endpoints (works locally though!)

Comment: I am trying to setup the same for Node api, but I am not able to access the endpoint after deploying. I followed all sets mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine)

I followed [THIS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/openapi-appengine.yaml) get started guide, but still not able to do so. I can see my Services being created but when I try to use it doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints does not currently support the root path at "/". This is something that is being looked into.

Comment: Any documentation/official word regarding this?