# Google Cloud Endpoint at "/" Method does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

```
{
 "code": 5,
 "message": "Method does not exist.",
 "details": [
  {
   "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
   "stackEntries": [],
   "detail": "service_control"
  }
 ]
}
```

My Cloud Endpoints deployment seems to work fine except when trying to load the root path (at "/"). The endpoint appears in the console, but trying to load it outputs the error above.

I've searched all over but can only find one reference to it anywhere (on mobile now but will add it here when I find it again).

Comment: I think we will need more information in order to help you with your issue. With the information you shared, I only found reference to that same "Method does not exist" error in a page in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/esp-troubleshooting#method_does_not_exist), however it applies to the use of the Extensible Service Proxy, so you can have a look at the link and see if it helps you.

A part from that, maybe you can share the configuration of you Cloud Endpoints deployment, in order to see where the potential issue might be.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me so quick. 
What I had found was on stackoverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097453/google-cloud-endpoints-method-does-not-exist-openapi-yaml-specification

Comment: Oops - enter sends the comment here. On that link someone mentions that '/' isn't supported but I can't find reference to that in any google documentation. I'm happy to share the configuration though.

Comment: Can you provide more information in the [context](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/) in which you are using Endpoints? Is it with OpenAPI or with Frameworks? Are you using an App Engine application (if so, Standard or Flexible)? Moreover, it will be useful if you can share the configuration files or some code of your API and/or endpoints. P.S.: you can edit a comment in StackOverflow within 5 minutes of posting them by clicking on the "Edit" button next to it.

Comment: @JasonHill that's sort of my impression too, that `/` is not supported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Cloud Endpoints does not currently support the root path at "/". The documentation will be updated to reflect this soon.
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations

Comment: Wow, wasted hours trying to troubleshoot this. This caveat really should be more prominent in the documentation. Standard practice when going through tutorials or testing a new product is to hit the root of an API. At the very least, the error message returned should be more useful.